# Android ShapeDrawable Translate Transform

Tags: android, graphics, android-gui

I have a class that extends View, in which I place an instance of a `ShapeDrawable`, using `shapeDrawable.draw(canvas)` in the `onDraw()` method.

I would like to create a translate animation that would move the `ShapeDrawable` object to another (x,y) position in a given amount of time.

Is there a simple way to achieve this in Android 1.6?
Or is there something that I can change in my approach that could help simplify this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could try this Although you would have to add a timer

```java
public void changePos (float dx, float dy) {
    mPosX += dx;
    mPosY += dy;
    this.invalidate ();
}
```